# Split Associative Array by Specific Keys

Tags: php, arrays

This seems like it should be easy but I'm having difficulties finding a function to do this.

I have an array like

```
Array
(
    [2338] => 181684562467
    [2550] => 181645662467
    [2658] => 182345645567
    [2878] => 171756765267
)
```

I need to be able to specify the keys manually `2658`, `2878`.

And based off my inputted values split the array into two arrays

```
Array
(
    [2338] => 181684562467
    [2550] => 181645662467
)
```

&

```
Array
(
    [2658] => 182345645567
    [2878] => 171756765267
)
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Here is how the array is originally being generated (via a MySQL Query)

```
$itemidquery = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_itemids';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $itemidquery);
$data_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_array[$row['post_id']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, by manually you mean, via user input?

Comment: By manually I mean I know the keys I want to split `2658` `2878`.  The actual array is a large list of 100+ and I want to specify the exact keys I wish to split.

Comment: How do you insert the keys you want?

Comment: @pr1nc3 I edited the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


$array=Array
(
    2338 => 181684562467,
    2550 => 181645662467,
    2658 => 182345645567,
    2878 => 171756765267
);
//you set the values of the array seperated with comma!!!
$name = $_GET["name"];
if($name!=''){

    //get the multiple values that are seperated by comma and create an array of them
$data=explode(',',$name);

    $myArray=array();
foreach($data as $row){
    //check if the key you insert exists in the array, if it does it inserts the value in the new array
    if(array_key_exists ($row,$array)){
        $myArray[]=$array[$row];
    }

}

//the output based on the keys you insert
print_r($myArray);
}
```

Added comments to help you understand my code. I had to create a static array for your example. I am using GET method to retrieve the data.

sample link :

```
http://localhost/testing_project.php?name=2658,2338
```

Comment: Thank you.  Looking into this trying to revise.  It's not splitting per-say (as in preserving the key's of the original array), but creating a new array.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  To preserve the key involves just simply revising `$myArray[$row] = $data_array[$row];`